# How to stop showing menu in static home page

Tags: menus

Ok, I'm creating a wordpress theme. I don't want my navigation menu to show in the home page "Only" if the site admin setup Front page displays > A static page (select below).

otherwise I want to show the menu in home page & other pages too. I've used this `<?php if(!is_front_page()):?>` function, but it is not working.

some one suggest me "`<?php if(!is_home()):?>`", but it is not working either.

So how do I make it work?

Full code:

```
<?php if(!is_home()):?>
    <!-- NAVIGATION START -->
    <div id="navigation">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">
              <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-sm-2">
                              <div class="site-logo">
                                <a href="index.html" class="brand">ajax</a>
                              </div>
                          </div>                          

                          <div class="col-sm-10"> 

                              <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                              <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
                                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                                </button>
                              </div>
                              <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
                                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
                                'theme_location' => 'secondary', 
                                'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right', 
                                'fallback_cb' => 'false' 
                                )); ?>
                              </div>
                              <!-- /.Navbar-collapse -->

                          </div>
                    </div> <!--bootstrap row end-->
              </div> <!--bootstrap container end-->
        </nav>
    </div> 
    <!--NAVIGATION END -->
    <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: What template file are you using for the home page? Index.php, home.php, or front-page.php?

Comment: I'm using index.php

Comment: Hmmm. It seems !is_home() should work. Interesting...

Comment: I've added the full code, could you check please & tell me if I'm doing anything wrong?

Comment: Hint: Use the plugin Debug Objects to find, which Conditional Tag was fired on this page.

Comment: This may be pointless / weird, but can you try using brackets instead of a colon?  if (!is_home()) {   And instead of "endif;" , just use a "}" for closing the statement?

Comment: Be sure to add a space before "?>"

Comment: tried, but not working.

Comment: @bueltge I've installed that plugin, but how to use it??? never used it before!

Comment: ok I find it, but according to this plugin maybe "is_home" is firing. it has different color than others.

Comment: yaap....got it... "is_home" function working!! that is very very strange

Comment: but it is only work in the home page now.

Comment: The plugin give you the information, which Conditional tag is true. If is a static home page, maybe defined as template on a page of WordPress, then is also `is_page` active. You can check for this with `is_page( [ID of the page])`.